# Why are those two mesh regions not the same?

Tags: mesh

In Mathematica, one can triangulate a mesh starting from a boundary mesh region. For example:

```
r = BoundaryMeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 2}}, Line[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1}]]
m = TriangulateMesh[r, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]
```

gives a mesh `m` with an L shape.

From `m`, it is possible to define another mesh as:

```
m2 = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[m], MeshCells[m, 2]]
```

Based on my understanding for `MeshRegion`, `m2` should be the same as `m`. Sure enough if we check the mesh primitives, they are the same:

```
MeshPrimitives[m2] == MeshPrimitives[m]
(* True *)
```

However, if we compare `m` and `m2` directly, we find that they are not equal:

```
m2==m
(* False *)
```

So why are they not equal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The region `m` appears to have an extra option set, causing them to be considered different regions:

```
m // Options
(* {Method -> {"PropagateMarkers" -> False}} *)

m2 // Options
(* {} *)
```

If you copy the options of `m` into `m2`, the two regions will be the same:

```
m2 = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[m], MeshCells[m, 2], Options[m]];

m == m2
(* True *)
```